# Delphi 5 App crashed with 'EInvalidPointer' when Hyper-Threading enabled, upgrade IDE will work?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, controls

I'm designing an application for an asphalt batch mix plant, using a thread to run the mixing process, several timers to read system states and perform control actions.

If "`Hyper-Threading`" features is `disabled`, the application will run smoothly, everything is OK; or it will bring up a dialog grumbling that memory access is invalid and abort immediately after click "OK".

Don't know why? Maybe something wrong with IDE version, since Delphi 5 was released at 10th August 1999; maybe the thread unit in Delphi 5.0 cannot deal with new CPU technology?

Maybe memory management has some bugs, maybe the thread mode is not suitable for new era?

I want to upgrade the IDE, but since there are many many years pasted, I have no idea which would be the best choice,
Delphi 7? Delphi 2007(which support OmniThreadLibrary)? RAD Studio XE6/7? Hope someone will help.

Comment: I'm not sure why you imagine this is something to do with D5; frankly it's far more likely to be a problem with your code, because people have been successfully writing and running multi-threaded D5 applications since it came out.

Comment: Definitely: it sounds like typical race condition error which appears while real paralelism is enabled

Comment: Thanks MartynA and pf1957. These days it pains me a lot, the original codes were written 12 years ago, last year I upgrade it to 2013 version with generic driver unchanged, the problem only remind me of driver compatibility but not thread bug; this year I substitute the generic DAQ card driver with a serial communications layer which deal with 6 devices, the application fails when all the modules integrated and system gets run. The tester try to disable the Hyper-Threading feature in BIOS, everything seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

The most plausible explanation is that your program has a bug related to threading. You happen to get away with the flaw in your code when hyperthreading is disabled, but enabling it is sufficient to make the error in your code manifest.

Threading bugs are just like this. They will manifest if threads execute specific code in a particular order, with respect to the other threads. And the relative ordering is unpredictable. Which is part and parcel of parallel computation. Code that is broken can appear to be correct when running under one environment, but then fail under another. Whilst it is tempting to blame the tools, always check in the mirror first.

Changing development environment is not the solution. What you need to do is to find and then fix the error in your code. Getting a good stack trace will help, and I can recommend a tool like madExcept for that.

Comment: Thanks for quick answering. I try EurekaLog 7.0.7.1 for trapping the crash points but fails. Maybe the newer Delphi IDE with improved memory management and thread pattern will solve the problem? The application was first released at 2002, it's painful to maintain code lines written 12 years before. Maybe I must inspect the codes more carefully.

Comment: The IDE is not relevant. You are clutching at straws. Please don't make me repeat what I said in the answer ;-)

Comment: This is a classic scenario. The evidence clearly points to your code. But you cannot face the pain of debugging this horrid code. So you look for a magic quick fix. Human nature.

Comment: Since Delphi 5 is so antique, and CPU structure has many affects to the way thread works. I'm afraid going the wrong way. The time is so urgent, since user will not wait for too long.

Comment: The most efficient use of time is to try to isolate the problem with the development tool that you have at hand. Upgrading to a modern Delphi will take a very long time and introduce more problems that need to be resolved. If you have a tight deadline, the smart move is to debug the code you have, in the dev environment that was used to develop it.

Comment: OK. I have tried for a whole week, eyes red, neck stiff, users nagging. Maybe you' re right, what I need is more patience. Master hand is hard to locate around here. I want to try XE6 too. Thanks.

Comment: XE6? Then you'll have to upgrade all your libraries, and deal with the ANSI to Unicode transition. Vast swathes of your code will not compile. It will take you weeks to deal with all of that. And then you'll still have to find the original bug. Which will still be there.

Comment: Upgrading to XE6 (or any version from 2010 and on) will incur a completely different set of problems - UNICODE support, which may turn out to be a much bigger problem than finding the error in your code using D5 (depending on the size of your application).

Comment: Not a recommended approach, but... You can try to disable hyperthreading from within your program using GetProcessAffinityMask and SetProcessAffinityMask - at least as a temporary stopgap measure while you hunt down the real problem. That way, the user can run your program without it crashing and without forcing him to disable HyperThreading system wide. But only use this as a temporary solution - hunt down the real culprit and fix it...

Comment: Thank HeartWare. Maybe I should get it run and find time to locate the bug. Surely a lot of gurus on line here. I will try much harder. Thanks for you all.

Comment: Somebody still there? I just install madExcept and open my project, activate madExcept, rebuild, everything OK, but, when quitting Delphi 5, the madExcept traps an error in the Delphi IDE! It says:
exception number   : 3
exception class    : EAccessViolation
exception message  : Access violation at address 40004B80 in module 'Vcl50.bpl'. Read of address 0000FFF8.

Comment: Does that means Delphi 5 has native bugs, which maybe the cause too?

Comment: How could an IDE AV be responsible for an access violation in your process? I can understand that you find it hard to believe that your code could contain a fault, but eventually you will have to face up to it. It's obviously up to you to determine how to proceed, but you asked our advice and the response was unanimous. You may choose to ignore it and go your own way, but there's little to be gained in asking us to bless that decision of yours. I doubt you'll find anyone to bless it. Of course, you may be right, and we are all wrong, but it's for you to judge that.

Comment: Thanks David Heffernan. I'm just afraid going wrong direction since it's urgent. I have built many applications since 1992, begining with X86 and MCS-51 assembler. Now I pay more time writing program for DSP-based embedded system. The Hyper-Threading problem first found me at 2002, I thought something wrong with Advantech card driver...

Comment: My code surely not perfect, no software is perfect. Users and I just need something really works, we cannot solve every problem. Anyway, Thanks everybody here, I will pay more time to identify the bugs of my design there. Thanks a lot.